# Camel Redirecting to another route on throttling

Tags: apache-camel, throttling

I have a camel route which will be throttled on recieving loads of messages. Suppose the maximum exchanges i defined is 3 per 2 seconds and the route recieves more than the limit i want to redirect those messages to some other load balancer route. Can someone help me how to achieve it??

Comment: Maybe you can change your route and use loadbalancing before throttling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question right you want to throttle your incoming messages then loadbalance those messages out to a different route or system.

```
from("SomethingSendingMeMessages")
    .throttle(3)
    .loadbalance().roundRobin()
        .to("place1", "place2", "place3")
    .end();
```

If you need to have the throttling route send to a second route that contains the loadbalancer you can do it like follows:

```
from("SomethingSendingMeMessages")
    .throttle(3)
    .to("direct:mySecondRoute");

from("direct:mySecondRoute")
    .loadbalance().roundRobin()
        .to("place1", "place2", "place3")
    .end();
```

Another option you could explore is throttling after the loadbalancer to control each individual route's method.

```
from("SomethingSendingMeMessages")
    .loadbalance().roundRobin()
        .to("direct:place1", "direct:place2")
    .end();

from("direct:place1")
    .throttle(3)
    .to("myOtherWork");

from("direct:place2")
    .throttle(3)
    .to("myOtherWork");
```